# Card display same size featured image no matter size of uploaded image

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a website and we have a press section. The page automatically loads the articles from the database, but I'm having a cosmetic issue.

Basically, the cards the articles sit in (aside from the featured article) all size differently based on the image.

What I'm looking to do is keep each card the same size. My thought is to have it show the same size image no matter the actual size of the image uploaded **I hope that makes sense.**

Is it possible to do this? Can anyone lead/guide me to how it can be done?

Below is an image of what it currently looks like. What I want to do is make every card the same size. So, sort of, create a mask that displays a specific size:

[image: different size cards due to image size]

Comment: Just set a fixed height and width on the images. Though, you'd face issues with the proportions. Alternatively, use background-image in CSS https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp and set background: cover

Comment: @Dammeul I've set the fixed h/w on them, and yea, I deal with the ratio issues which is what I'm trying to avoid. I'm kind of thinking how to create a frame where the image sites and then what doesn't fit in the frame is hidden. Think of a masking effect in photoshop

Comment: Yeah my example showing background-image use is what you're after!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two examples based on my comment, obviously, I'm unsure of your actually code

One way:

```
<style>
.card-image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px
}
</style>    
<div class="card">
   <img src="path/to/image.jpg" class="card-image" alt="Alt Text"/>
</div>
```

Another:

```
<style>
.card-image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px
  background-image:url("path/to/image.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
}
</style>    
<div class="card">
   <div class="card-image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was exactly it! Thank you so much!